# Syntax Out Of Range Unhandled

Tags: vb.net

I'm a bit of a newbie so any advice would be great. I have a program 
that opens a CSV, and then saves it as a csv with a different name. there will be a set of rules to change fields but haven't got that far yet.

when I run this on a small csv file (about 4 columns and rows) it works fine, but with a larger file, it fails with the error above. i'm sure its something daft but I I'm at a loss.

Thanks,

Dean

```
    Dim FileName = tbOpen.Text
    Dim fileout = tbSave.Text
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileName)
    Dim output As New List(Of String)

    For Each line In lines
        Dim fields = line.Split(","c)

        If fields(1) = "" Then        'This is where the error is triggered
            fields(1) = "Norman"
        End If
        If fields(3) = "" Then
            fields(3) = "Blue Leather"
        End If
        If fields(4) = "" Then
            fields(3) = "Interlined"
        End If

        output.Add(String.Join(","c, fields))
    Next
    File.WriteAllLines(fileout, output)


    Try

        Dim a As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(tbSave.Text)
        Dim b As String() = a.Split(vbNewLine)
        ListBox2.Items.AddRange(b)
    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox("error")

    End Try
```

Comment: You realy should use [Option Strict and Option Explicit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311329).

Comment: _"Syntax Out Of Range"_ lol, that is really good ^^

Comment: Have you run through it in debug mode with some breakpoints in? Can you point to the line the error occurs on?

Comment: the specific error is "Index was outside the bounds of the array." the line of code was on If fields(1) = "abc" Then

Comment: Stop messing around with this and let the [TextFieldParser Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do the work for you.

Comment: This error will be thrown when you are trying to "use" something, which actually dose not exist. In your case, the error is thrown probably because there is no `fields(1)`, i.e `fields` is empty.

Comment: your correct that it is because there is more fields than is declared in the array. how would I increase the array to have more fields, e.g. 40 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that arrays start a index 0.  VB is notorious for stretching this concept.  Normally, when you declare an array with 10 elements the indexes would be from 0 - 9.  With VB, on the other hand, the indexes will be from 0 - 10 which will actually give you 11 elements.